# mysql connection profiles configuration file

Tags: mysql, linux

Is there a way to save the connection params(like host, port, username, password, db) to the mysql servers I frequently access as shortcuts?

I am looking for something similar to [ssh config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for mysql from terminal in ubuntu. preferably with ssh tunneling support as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the --defaults-file option combined with an shell alias,
for example:

```
% cat db01
[mysql]
user=root
password=<your_pwd>
host=<your_host>


% alias my_db01='mysql --defaults-file=db01'

% my_db01
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 41
Server version: 5.1.54-1ubuntu4 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL v2 license

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

So you can create different files with different settings.

Comment: i can directly add alias for mysql -uuser -ppassword -hhost instead of using a file. But, thats not what I am looking for. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, you can. It should be noted though that in that case on some operating systems your password will be clearly visible in the ps command output. If you want to avoid a separate file and your shell supports process substitution, you could use something like this: `mysql --defaults-file=<(printf '[mysql]\nuser=%s\npassword=%s\n' user pass)`, so in the ps output be: `mysql> \! pgrep -lf mysql\
 6312 mysql --defaults-file=/dev/fd/63`.